# SwingUtilities.invokeLater with infinite loop, not continuing?

Tags: java, swing, invokelater

I have an infinite while loop waiting for an event in `SwingUtilities.invokeLater` with `Runnable` interface but the execution is not continuing ... why?

```
//here hello3 prints in cmd but hello2 will not execute
System.out.println("hello3");

//showMessage();
SwingUtilities.invokeLater(
    new Runnable(){
        public void run() {
            while(true) {
                jEditorPane1.setText(s9);
            }
        }
    }
);

System.out.println("hello2");
```

Comment: Start with [Concurrency in Swing](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/). You're blocking the EDT. `invokeLater` executes the `run` method the `Runnable` on the EDT at some point in the future

Answer (score 3):

SwingUtilities.invokeLater will execute the run method inside the event-dispatching thread.

If all the code that you show us is being executed inside the event-dispatching thread (if it is being executed inside an actionListener for example) the thread is becoming "frozen" inside the infinite loop.

Comment: no its not in any handler im using netbeans form to design the gui but its generating all the gui code in one swingutilities.invokelater but im creating another method that include this code in this class which i will call using object created from this class

Comment: `Forum_main fm = new Forum_main();
             fm.setVisible(true);
             fm.getdata(uid, tid);
             close();`

Comment: ithe class invocation looks like this

Comment: inside main`java.awt.EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                new Forum_main().setVisible(true);
            }
        });`

Comment: in getdata() fuction `System.out.println("hello3");

//showMessage();
SwingUtilities.invokeLater(
    new Runnable(){
        public void run() {
            while(true) {
                jEditorPane1.setText(s9);
            }
        }
    }
);

System.out.println("hello2");`

Comment: You should edit your question to add info instead of using the comments.